# How can I getElementsByTagName from jQuery by converting it to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbytagname

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var remote_data = [
        {
            'path': '/var/www/html/somefile.php',
            'content': '<html><body><div class="navigation">Original data!</div></body></html>'
        },
        {
            'path': '/var/www/html/anotherfile.php',
             'content': '<html><body><div class="navigation">Original data!</div></body></html>'
        }
    ];

    var replacement = '<div class="test">New data</div>';
    for (i = 0; i < remote_data.length; i++)
    {
        var original = $('<header>' + remote_data[i].content + '<footer>', document);

        var doc = original.get();

        var elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('div');
        console.log(elems.length);
        for (j = 0; j < elems.length; j++)
        {
            alert(elems[j].className);
            if (elems[j].className == 'navigation')
            {
                alert(elems[j]);
            }
        }

        $(original).find('.navigation').html(replacement);
        document.write($(original).html());
    }
});
```

I want to call `var elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('div');` but this causes an error. I cannot use jQuery. I must use javascript to getElementsByTagName from the string. How can this be done?

Comment: I am confused, so you are using jQuery but you can't for this one instance?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `original.find('div')`? I guess I don't see why you *must* use `getElementsByTagName`. Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Because jQuery strips out javascript in my implimentation where the var 'content' has inline or included javascripts.

Comment: But you're looking for `div` elements?